# Mouse on multiple desktops

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I have a desktop extended over two monitors attached to my Windows XP workstation.

The second monitor is switched off most of the time (I only use it for JS debugging which I don't do often).

Is there any way to restrict the mouse area with one monitor and only allow moving between monitors when pressing a hotkey or something?

Comment: Not making this an answer, because buying new hardware would be silly, but most DisplayPort monitors nowadays act like USB devices in that if you shut them off while connected on DisplayPort, Windows will act like you disconnected them entirely (and remove that output accordingly). XP can be dicey about reenabling it later, but Vista/7 remember very well so you'd literally just need to power cycle.  On a more personal note, though, I can't fathom how you can't find a fulltime use for more screen real estate - I'm running four as we speak and I'd LOVE to cram a couple more onto this desk.

Comment: @Shinrai: as you can guess from my SO profile, I'm mostly an SQL developer and all my queries fit into one screen. When I have to work with even two monitors I feel like a cat watching tennis.

Comment: But...but...at the very least surely your email is open!  Don't cover it up! (I tease, in good faith)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several programs that will do that for you. A quick google search brought up
Mousetrap http://www.fxc.btinternet.co.uk/software.htm
and a multiple monitor controlling program that can be customized to do the same
http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x9wc9m_restrict-mouse-on-a-monitor-in-dual_tech
http://www.murgee.com/MurGeeMon/

Comment: Neat app! I like. (Oh, and welcome to Super User - I look forward to seeing more good content like this out of you!)

Answer (score 1):

I think the most simple solution would be to disable the monitor through Windows by right clicking the desktop and changing the properties / screen resolution options.  Do the reverse when you want to use the monitor.

Comment: Simple to implement maybe, but definitely not simple to use.

Comment: It takes a total of four clicks, in Windows 7, and five clicks in Windows XP, cannot get much simpler than that.

Comment: one key press with that MouseTrap thing is much more simple.